# Jenkins integration with Github plugin for Private repository

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, githooks

I have installed Jenkins in an Azure VM.
Version - 1.651.2

Path to Git :
[image]

Installed Plugins :
Credentials Plugin - 2.0.7
Git Hub Credentials Plugin - 0.24
Git Hub Plugin - 1.19.1
SSH Credentials Plugin - 1.12

[image]

[image]
In the repo Url tried both https and ssh with username/password and ssh/private key aswell, still unable to pull from git server.

Console Output :

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Staging Build
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/--/--.git
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe init C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Staging Build # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/---/---.git
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config --local credential.username jenkins # timeout=10
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Windows\TEMP\git7879671492423343442.credentials\" # timeout=10
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/---/---.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=2
ERROR: Timeout after 2 minutes
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/---/---.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1719)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1463)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:314)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:506)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1057)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1097)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

---

Note: https://github.com/--/--.git 
I have replace my repo names with --- for security purpose and I have checked urls don't mismatch.
What is going wrong here?

EDIT :

I am able to clone from gitbash successfully using both ssh and https url.
[image]
Added deploy keys in github repo aswell.